# Datepicker JQUERY not select input date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, jquery-plugins

I have jquery datepicker and try make select data for count. When click on input I get datepicker calendar and same time alert from input with message 1,aprill,21. If I chose date from datepicker I not get result from my function. If I chose message date I get NaN. So it is mean my datepicker select does not work. How I can fix it. Very tired with this plagin
My HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker error-place" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" placeholder="27/04/2021" required data-error="#datepicker">

var datepicker = $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    closeText: "Đóng",
    prevText: "Trước",
    nextText: "Sau",
    currentText: "Hôm nay",
    monthNames: ["Tháng một", "Tháng hai", "Tháng ba", "Tháng tư", "Tháng năm", "Tháng sáu", "Tháng bảy", "Tháng tám", "Tháng chín", "Tháng mười", "Tháng mười một", "Tháng mười hai"],
    monthNamesShort: ["Một", "Hai", "Ba", "Bốn", "Năm", "Sáu", "Bảy", "Tám", "Chín", "Mười", "Mười một", "Mười hai"],
    dayNames: ["Chủ nhật", "Thứ hai", "Thứ ba", "Thứ tư", "Thứ năm", "Thứ sáu", "Thứ bảy"],
    dayNamesShort: ["CN", "Hai", "Ba", "Tư", "Năm", "Sáu", "Bảy"],
    dayNamesMin: ["CN", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7"],
    weekHeader: "Tuần",
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    changeYear: true,
});
```

And function

```
 function GetBirthDate() {
        var flatpickr;
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-m-d",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var dt = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-m-d", dateText);
                flatpickr = dt.getFullYear();
                console.log("Birth Year: " + flatpickr);
            }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem with the callback or the datepicker.
You are using the wrong date format for parsing the date.
It should be 'dd/mm/yy' instead of 'yy-m-d'.

The code should look this, (look at the onSelect function):

```js
var datepicker = $("#datepicker").datepicker({
  closeText: "Đóng",
  prevText: "Trước",
  nextText: "Sau",
  currentText: "Hôm nay",
  monthNames: ["Tháng một", "Tháng hai", "Tháng ba", "Tháng tư", "Tháng năm", "Tháng sáu", "Tháng bảy", "Tháng tám", "Tháng chín", "Tháng mười", "Tháng mười một", "Tháng mười hai"],
  monthNamesShort: ["Một", "Hai", "Ba", "Bốn", "Năm", "Sáu", "Bảy", "Tám", "Chín", "Mười", "Mười một", "Mười hai"],
  dayNames: ["Chủ nhật", "Thứ hai", "Thứ ba", "Thứ tư", "Thứ năm", "Thứ sáu", "Thứ bảy"],
  dayNamesShort: ["CN", "Hai", "Ba", "Tư", "Năm", "Sáu", "Bảy"],
  dayNamesMin: ["CN", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7"],
  weekHeader: "Tuần",
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  firstDay: 1,
  isRTL: false,
  showMonthAfterYear: false,
  changeYear: true,
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var dt = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", dateText);
    console.log(dt);
    flatpickr = dt.getFullYear();
    console.log("Birth Year: " + flatpickr);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker error-place" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" placeholder="27/04/2021" required data-error="#datepicker">
```